# Which sentence is correct to say?

Tags: meaning, grammar

In a conversation, which of the two sentences below is grammatically correct?

> There was a party celebrating for my sister's marriage.
>
> There was a party which was being celebrated for my sister's marriage.

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se]

Comment: @Kris If you have any objection, i will remove it by today evening.

Comment: Why is there always this assumption that because there are two sentences to choose from, one has to be correct? Very often both examples are wrong, or are begging to be reworded. The preposition *for* works if it precedes the noun phrase: *There was a party **for** my sister's marriage/wedding* OR *There was a party **to** celebrate my sister's marriage/wedding*

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  party was being celebrated there. and you mean to say that we should not use those sentence. if you are right, please give me answer.

Comment: As a sentence "There was a party which was being celebrated for my sister's marriage" is a bit awkward, you don't normally celebrate a party, you celebrate an occasion (e.g. a birthday) with a party. Both your examples are a bit awkward, although understandable.

Comment: ok fine, Mari i got it.

Comment: See Jason Chen's answer. That sentence is perfectly fine.

Comment: I agree with Mari-Lou A. Both sentences are somehow awkward, however understandable. But Jason's offer is fine.

Answer (score 5):

The following sentence would be better.

> There was a party celebrating my sister's marriage.

Answer (score 3):

Both are wrong

> There was a party celebrating for my sister's marriage.

This is grammatically incorrect. You celebrate an event. You do not celebrate *for* an event.

> There was a party which was being celebrated for my sister's marriage.

This is incorrect (or at least very unlikely). What is being celebrated is the marriage. The first part of this sentence makes it seem that the event which you are celebrating is the party itself. A party is a type of celebration. You don't usually celebrate a celebration.

If you are recording a past event you might write

```
There was a party celebrating my sister's marriage
```

or, somewhat more passively,

```
There was a party in celebration of my sister's marriage.
```

or

```
There was a party to celebrate my sister's marriage.
```

Answer (score 2):

Out of the two choices, I agree with @Jason Chen. However, I would rewrite the sentence completely:

> We [he/she/they] celebrated my sister's marriage with a party.